# How can I remove ellipsis from Vtiger 6.3 text?

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

I am using Vtiger 6.3.

I need to remove the ellipsis from the organization (контрагент) text field and render the full name of organization. Please see the screenshot below.

[[image: 1]]

I found a CSS file and commented out all styles but the dots are still present.

I went deeper into the PHP files and found that Vtigercrm gets the data from the database and parses it in its code. But I can not see where it formats the text.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are talking about values which get trimmed after certain length in List view of Module.

The function which doing this trimming is called `function textlength_check($field_val)` and its present in *vtiger_root/include/utils/ListViewUtils.php*,

Trimming happens in this function `function getListViewRecords($focus, $module, $result)` and its present in this file *vtiger_root/include/ListView/ListViewController.php*, Also have a look on  line number 364(vtiger 6.4), they are doing it as custom for multipicklist,

You can also increase the size of listview value by changing this `$listview_max_textlength = 40;` (Default length is 40)configuration in *vtiger_root/config.inc.php*

HTH